# How to stop quotes from being replaced by html entities

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of values as follows

```
invited = ["555665", "66996"]
```

When I put this in a javascript function it becomes

```
[&quot;555665&quot;,&quot;66996&quot; ]),
```

Here is my code:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        exclude_ids: escape(<%=@exclude_users.to_s%>),
        message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
}
```

Comment: Does it not work when you send the data?

Comment: Its giving me an error in my javascript. The FB.UI does not like it

Comment: Maybe, `<%= raw @exclude_users.inspect %>`

Comment: I don't understand.  How does `invited` relate to the `FB.ui()` call? What do you mean by "When I put this in a javascript function"?

Comment: yes that is it. but without the inspect. Taro post this as an answer so I can award you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want credit to go to Taro but he did not post the answer so I am posting. If the Stackoverflow management can credit him then please do so.

I used `<%= raw @exclude_users %>` and it worked.

Thanks to Taro